# Document.write and windows.location together in IE is not working

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-11, window.location, document.write

I'm having a strange behavior and I'm fighting with myself in order to figure out what error can be.

I have an HTML page that, on body load, checks for the presence of a Variable "TRANSACTIONVALUE" in query string. 
If the string is present and has specific value (8374), user is redirected to a specific page (let's call it "backend page").
Due that sometimes this "backend page" is a bit slow (it fires an agent that sometimes goes down for inactivity, so need to wait to reactivate it), i resolved it just adding a document.write that says just "Request in course... Please wait" in the same blanked page before the redirect.

My code is working for ALL browser, except for Internet Explorer where users are blocked in the first statement "document.write".

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="us">
  <head>
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="CONTENT-TYPE" CONTENT="TEXT/HTML;CHARSET=UTF-8">
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="PRAGMA" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="EXPIRES" CONTENT="-1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="../../../../favicon.ico">
  <script>
function CheckHeaderStatus() {
    if (getQueryVariable("TRANSACTIONVALUE")==8374)
        {
          document.write("Request in course... Please wait");
          window.location.href='http://backendapplication.goto.com/Default.aspx?TARGET='+TRANSACTIONVALUE;  
    }
}     
</script>    
  </head>
  <body onload="CheckHeaderStatus()" class="text-center">
      
<div> any text <div>
  </body>
</html>
```

What happens is that it works for Chrome, Safari, Firefox. In these cases if an user has the TRANSACTIONVALUE=8374, on body load he can see the "Request in course... Please wait" message and then is redirect to the page http://backendapplication.goto.com/Default.aspx?TARGET='+TRANSACTIONVALUE

Now, in Internet Explorer users with TRANSACTIONVALUE=8374 can see ONLY the "Request in course... Please wait" message. The page stop to go head and so they are not redirect to the other page.
What can be the problem?

I have tested other way to obtain the same (as proven of my work) like:
"Remove all content from the page, create a div where I can write the massage of waiting, and then redirect, so:

```js
while (document.firstChild) {
document.removeChild(document.firstChild);  
};


// create new DIV
var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
  newDiv.innerHTML = "<h1>Request in course... Please wait</h1>";
window.location.href='http://backendapplication.goto.com/Default.aspx?TARGET='+TRANSACTIONVALUE;
```

but again, it works for all browser expect for IE. I tested with IE9,10,11.
I'm missing something or it is a problem of IE?

Thanks all!!!

Comment: Are there any errors shown in the console in the developer tools (press F12)?

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved in this way:

```js
function CheckHeaderStatus() {
    if (getQueryVariable("TRANSACTIONVALUE")==8374)
        {
  Redirect();
            function Redirect() {
          document.write("Request in course... Please wait");
          window.location.href='http://backendapplication.goto.com/Default.aspx?TARGET='+TRANSACTIONVALUE;  
    }
}}
```

In this way it works also for IE :-)